# why sort query is not working in mongoldb?

Tags: mongodb

sort query is not working on mongodb I am displaying mat-table using pagination for that sort query is not working code reference :
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

as shown in below query sortactive is column name like(name, ordered,email) and sortorder is direction for sort like asc or desc it is in 1 & -1 .

```
collection.aggregate([
     { '$match': { 'status': { $ne: "cancel" } }},
     { '$sort': { sortactive:  sortorder }},
     {'$skip': skips },{ '$limit': pageSize }],{ allowDiskUse: true })
```

resulted of the query should be according to column sort.

Comment: You cannot use object literal syntax for a dynamic key, only the value can be a variable. You have to do something like `const sort = {}; sort[sortactive] = sortorder;` and include that in your query object.

Comment: var sortOperator = { "$sort": { } },
sort = sortactive;
sortOperator["$sort"][sort] = sortorder;      collection.aggregate(sortOperator) this is working.